# Loud crackle from home button on iPhone 8

Tags: iphone, audio

Ive got a iPhone 8, running iOS 11.4 latest sub version.

As i understand on the latest iPhones (i think from 7 onwards) the home button is not a touch button but rather an inbuilt Taptic engine which is kind of like a rumble pack, this combined with the speaker create a faux user feedback for the home button.

Recently when pressing the home button i have been getting a loud electronic crackel which sounds like the faux feedback through the speaker but about 10 times louder and distorted.

This has happened a couple of times and clears after a few clicks, but comes back.

Apart from taking it to the Apple store is there anything i can do to address the issue. The phone is within warranty but id prefer not to have to go to an apple store if i dont have to.

Comment: Is it even documented that the haptic feedback uses the speaker? I know for sure there is a mechanical actuator that probably isn’t totally silent when it works properly. I’d love to hear a recording of what you’re hearing - any change you can upload that somewhere and edit the post so we can hear what you are hearing?

Comment: @bmike next time it happens ill try get a recording